# CSV to ORC conversation in Azure Error : found more columns than expected column count

Tags: azure-data-factory

Am pushing csv files pipe(|) delimited from one storage account in azure to another storage account  using the ORC file format but it throws an error:

```
Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'time.csv' with row number 122277 found more columns than expected column count
```

how do I solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

> 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'time.csv' with row number 122277 found
>   more columns than expected column count

Based on the error, it indicates that your columns violate the below 3rd rule which is mentioned in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-column-mapping).

- Source data store query result does not have a column name that is
  specified in the input dataset "structure" section.
- Sink data store (if with pre-defined schema) does not have a column
  name that is specified in the output dataset "structure" section.
- Either fewer columns or more columns in the "structure" of sink
  dataset than specified in the mapping.
- Duplicate mapping.

You need to check whether the row number `122277` source columns are divided into different constants with `|` delimitation so that it can't map to the sink columns.

Comment: I am facing the same situation in Azure Data Factory (copy csv from blob storage to Data Explorer)
My CSV file have values like this "123,456", which I think cause this error.
However, I check "preview data", it looks pretty good.
Any suggestions?